# Postprocessing key for videovformat converting in Youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

There is an example of Postprocessing in Youtube-dl [wiki page](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#embedding-youtube-dl) for audio extracting but I could not do the same thing for video format converting. I am aware that there are options to select the video format before downloading but sometimes my desired format isn't available so I need to convert the downloaded video file. What is the `key` and other parameters to be passed?

```
    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio/best[height<=480]',
    'videoformat' : "mp4",
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'writethumbnail': True,
    'writesubtitles': True,
    'writeautomaticsub': True,
    'subtitleslangs': 'en',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',    #what to use for video format converting?
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',        #what to use for video format converting?
        'preferredquality': '192',      #what to use for video format converting?
    }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The available postprocessors are listed in [`postprocessor/__init__.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/cc42941390b547ba950b4e76f4950be801f96134/youtube_dl/postprocessor/__init__.py#L25-L40):

```
ydl_opts = {
    # ...
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor',
        'preferedformat': 'mp4',  # one of avi, flv, mkv, mp4, ogg, webm
    }],
}
```

(A better name for that key would have been `convert_to`, but changing it now would needlessly break compatibility.)

Comment: Thanks. What are the parameters for `FFmpegEmbedSubtitle` and `FFmpegSubtitlesConvertor` ?

Comment: And what hooks should be used for postprocessors?

Comment: At the moment, postprocessors don't have hooks. You are welcome to add a patch to that effect though. To find out the parameters for other postprocessors, either look into their source code, or in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/cc42941390b547ba950b4e76f4950be801f96134/youtube_dl/__init__.py#L249-L310).

Comment: webm apparently doesn't work, I geti this [ffmpeg] Converting video from mp4 to webm, Destination: /tmp/bu3Nmu_X6y4.webm
ERROR: Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0